# How can I display today's full date in a specific format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found examples for displaying date but I need it in a specific format, ie: 15 Jun 2018, but the months are shortened

[Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec]

So need it to display todays date in the above format.

```
  var monthShortNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
];

function dateFormat2(d) {
  var t = new Date(d);
  return t.getDate() + ' ' + monthShortNames[t.getMonth()] + ', ' + t.getFullYear();
}

//console.log(dateFormat2(new Date()))
var showDate = dateFormat2(new Date())

document.getElementById("todays-date").innerHTML = showDate + 14:44;
```

Then trying to output it in a div here:

```
<div id="todays-date"></div>
```

Can't seem to get it working. If there's a better way please let me know. Thanks

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: You can use momentjs library for date formatting

Answer (score 0):

I converted the code to a string, then split it by spaces. From there I was able to splice the array as needed.

```js
function dateFormat2(d) {
  var date = d.toString().split(" ");
  return `${date.splice(1, 2).reverse().join(" ")} ${date[1]}`;
}
var showDate = dateFormat2(new Date());
document.getElementById("todays-date").innerHTML = showDate;
```

```html
<div id="todays-date"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full working example

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var monthShortNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    ];

    function getTime(t) {
        let hours = t.getHours(); 
        if(hours.toString().length == 1) {
            hours = "0" + hours;
        }
        let minutes = t.getMinutes(); 
        if(minutes.toString().length == 1) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
        }
        return hours + ':' + minutes;
    }
    function dateFormat2() {
        var t = new Date();
        return t.getDate() + ' ' + monthShortNames[t.getMonth()] + ', ' + t.getFullYear() + ' ' + getTime(t);
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dateFormat2();
```

[click here for working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yx3obhvg/1/)

Answer (score -1):

It wasn't printing out the date, needed this:

```
document.getElementById("todays-date").innerHTML = (dateFormat2(new Date()));
```